# How to save the response info in the Redux state after fetch into useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I have the following case:

> ```
>     export default function Names() {
>     const dispatch = useDispatch();
>     const [names, setNames] = useState([]);
>     const stateNames = useSelector(state => state.names);
>
>     const fetchNames = async () => {
>     try {
>         const response = await nameService.getNames();
>         dispatch(initNames(response.body));
>         setNames(response.body);
>     } catch (error) {
>         console.error('Fetch Names: ', error);
>     }
>     };
>   
>     useEffect(() => {
>       fetchNames();
>     }, []);
>
>     return (
>            { names.map((name, index) => (
>              <Tab label={ budget.label} key={index}/>
>            )) }
>     );
>   }
> ```

When my component is rendered in the browser console I get a warning: "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchBudgets'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks / exhaustive-deps".
If I comment the line in which I write the names in Redux state, the warning does not appear.
I need the list of names in the state so that I can update the list when a new name is written to the list from the outside.

```
export default function AddNameComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [label, setLabel] = useState('');
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');

  const onLabelChange = (event) => { setLabel(event.target.value); };
  const onDescriptionChange = (event) => { setDescription(event.target.value); };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    try {
      event.preventDefault();
      const newName = {
        label: label
        description: description
      };
      const answer = await budgetService.postNewName(newName);
      dispatch(add(answer.body)); // Adding new Name in to Redux state.names
    } catch (error) {
      setErrorMessage(error.message);
      console.error('Create Name: ', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      // Create name form
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is how everything works, but I don't understand why I have a warning.
I tried to add a flag to the array with dependencies of usеЕffect.
I tried to pass the function 'fetchNames' through the parent component - in props and to add it as a dependency, but it is executed twice ...
Can you advise please!

Answer (score 1):

It's just an eslint warning so you don't *have* to fix it.  But basically any variables which are used in the `useEffect` function are expected to be included in the dependency array.  Otherwise, the effect will never be re-run even if the function `fetchBudgets` were to change.

It is expecting your hook to look like

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchBudgets();
}, [fetchBudgets]);
```

Where the effect will run once when the component is mounted and run again any time that the `fetchBudgets` function changes (which is probably never).

If it's executing more than once, that means that `fetchBudgets` has changed and you should try to figure our where and why it has been redefined.  Maybe it needs to be memoized?

[Here are the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) on putting functions in the dependency array.

Comment: When I put the function in the array, endless fetching of names begins.I try...

Comment: Where does “fetchBudgets” come from?  Can you define the function inside the useEffect hook?

Comment: Sorry I got a typo in my question code example. I fixed the call in useEffect to be to fetchNames.

Comment: Gotcha.  Try moving the block of code where you define the function to inside of the useEffect.

Comment: Yeah! Everything working fine! I no have more warnings! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your attention! I tried many options and finally found one solution.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchNames() {
      const response = await nameService.getNames();
      dispatch(init(response.body));
      setNames(response.body);
    }

    fetchNames();
  }, [dispatch, props]);
```

I put 'props' in an array of dependencies for one useEffect execution.